# make conditions with logical operators into variable

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

i want to make condition with logical operators (&& or ||) into one varialbe with concatination, and then run into if ($var)...

```
<?php 
$ar = array(
'index1' => array('bedrooms'=> '1','suburb' => 'one'),
'index2' => array('bedrooms'=>'2', 'suburb'=>'two')
);
$userValBed = '1';
$userSuburb = 'one';

$c = '';
$c .= '($value["'.'bedrooms'.'"] == "'.$userValBed.'") && ';
$c .= '($value["'.'suburb'.'"] == "'.$userSuburb.'")';

foreach($ar as $key => $value){
   if($c): // here occurs problem, please fix this.
   // if($value["bedrooms"] == "1" && $value["suburb"] == "one"): // comment this line, and uncommet above 'if'.
   echo "<br>";
   echo "this condtions matches to ";
   echo $key . ' key '. '<br>';
endif;
}
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\search-code.php(128) : eval()'d code on line 1

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is a `Command pattern`. The command pattern seeks to wrap up functionality inside of a class. The advantage of this is that you can swap out functionality at run time by specifying what you would like in the config. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is a more in depth explanation.

```
class Command {
    function doSomething($v1, $v2);
}
```

Then you create sub classes of that class:

```
class CommandAdd extends Command
{
    function doSomething($v1, $v2)
    {
         return $v1 === $v2;
    }
}
```

You can make as many classes with `doSomething` as you want. Then all you have to do is define your functionality:

```
$command = new CommandAdd();

if($command->doSomething()) { 
   // Code here 
}
```

You can specify the type of `Command` in an external file, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Putting code into variables is not a good design. It may work, but it's ugly and hard to understand.

Instead, you may use inner *foreach* for checking wheter the user's parameters matches the item's parameters.

Anyway, it's even better to store the data in some kind of database, say, SQL database, so the problem will change to: how to create SQL query from user's parameters.